# Video lectures for Commutative Algebra

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, online-resources

Are there any good video lectures for learning commutative algebra at level of Atiyah-Macdonald?

Comment: I doubt there are any.`

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any video lectures, but I found an open source MIT course with some problems and reading material. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-705-commutative-algebra-fall-2008/download-course-materials/

Answer (score 11):

Here are A.V Jayanthan's lectures based on Atiyah-McDonald : http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111106098/ which builds upto the structure theorem of Artinian Rings and Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

Answer (score 5):

I do not know there are the video lecture of Commutative Algebra for the beginner. However, we have some lecture from MSRI's conferences, which are avaiable on archive.org.

For example, here is the lecture about the history of Commutative Algebra :
[C.A lecture](http://www.archive.org/details/lecture_10193)

You can browse in MSRI webpage, it contains more informations and videos avaiable, for example : [Commutative Algebra: Interactions with Homological Algebra and Representation Theory](http://www.msri.org/web/msri/scientific/workshops/show/-/event/Wm260)

Comment: Good videoes!But how to play or download?

Comment: @Strongart : You can follow the link in the website. We can directly download them, and we can play with the helping of Klite codec, which is avaiable here : http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_codec_pack.htm

Comment: I download the K-Lite Codec Pack 8.4.0,but cannot open it.I do not know much about the computer.

Comment: @Strongart: You could not open K-Lite Codec Pack or the videos? You just have to download it first and then double click to install the codecs. Then, enjoy the lecture :)

Comment: I can not open K-Lite Codec Pack and can not find the place to download MSRI videoes.

Comment: For the K-Lite Codec Pack, this is avaiable at many webpage, so you should do it on your own. For the videos of MSRI at archive, just click on the HTTP link on a box at left corner of the webpage, it will redirect you to place for download. On MSRI  webpage, there are some(not all) videos are avaiable, and if it avaiable, it will have download link next to.You did not consider my second link in my answer, did not you?

Comment: I find the reason now,the example "Commutative Algebra: Interactions with Homological Algebra and Representation Theory" is just special,there is a sentence "The speakers have declined to have their material posted on the web",but some other videoes can be download.Good videoes!

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/articlelist_1215048895_12_1.html).
A first course of commutative algebra(1-30) and some others, which is made all by myself! But the main language is Chinese (mixing some English), maybe you need someone to translate it (English title means pure English).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Borcherds has [a series of lectures on commutative algebra](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8yHsr3EFj53rSexSz7vsYt-3rpHPR3HB) forming an online course, roughly following Eisenbud's book.