# Books in commutative algebra

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation

I am reading "**Commutative ring theory**" by Matsumura, but find it a little hard. I wanted to find some reference books but found few books have the same details as CRT (for example, I can't find one with flatness in detail). So, please help me with some reference books.

Comment: Matsumura has a second version of his notes that is more acessible. There's also Atiyah and Macdonald's book, Eisenbud's book, and I have learned a nice deal from Pete Clark's notes.

Comment: I suggest you read bourbaki then. Experts agree that it is the best and most detailed treatise on CA

Comment: The books noted in my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757530/artinian-noetherian-rings-and-modules-suggest-study-guide/1757699#1757699). See also [this good question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303832/how-to-learn-commutative-algebra/1305198#1305198)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to learn commutative algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303832/how-to-learn-commutative-algebra)

Comment: @user1, just flagged as a possible duplicate.